# How can I show that $\int_0^T f(s)dW_s\sim \mathcal N\left(0, \int_0^T f(s)^2ds\right)$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Let $f$ a determinisitic functio in $L^2(0,T)$. How can I show that $$\int_0^T f(s)dW_s\sim \mathcal N\left(0,\int_0^T f(s)^2ds\right) \ \ ?$$

First of all, it's clear that $$\mathbb E\int_0^T f(s)dW_s=0$$
and 
$$\mathbb E\left(\int_0^T f(s)dW_s\right)^2=\int_0^T f(s)^2ds.$$

So, if $\int_0^T f(s)dW_s$ is normally distributed, then the claim follow. To prove it's normally distributed, I tried to use Itô formula with $g(x,t)=xf(t)$. This gives (as far as $f$ derivable)$$W_tf(t)=\int_0^t W_s f'(s)ds+\int_0^t f(s)dW_s,$$
but unfortunately, I can't conclude. Any idea ?

Comment: I decided to put my comments as an answer...see below.

Comment: @saz has a comprehensive answer. I just wanted to also point out that one can show $\exp(i\xi \int_0^T f(s) dW_s + \frac{1}{2} \xi^2 \int_0^T f(s)^2 ds)$ is a bona fide martingale by Ito and therefore its expectation must be 1. Rearranging, since f is deterministic, you get saz's last equation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Step 1:** If the assertion holds for all **continuous** deterministic $f \in L^2(0,T)$, then it holds for all deterministic $f \in L^2(0,T)$.

Proof: Fix a deterministic function $f \in L^2(0,T)$. By the denseness of the continuous functions, there exists a sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of continuous functions such that $f_n \to f$ in $L^2(0,T)$, i.e. $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^T |f_n(t)-f(t)|^2 \, dt = 0. \tag{1}$$ By Itô's isometry, this implies that the stochastic integral $X_n := \int_0^T f_n(s) \, dW_s$ converges in $L^2(\mathbb{P})$ to $X:=\int_0^T f(s) \, dW_s$. Since $f_n$ is continuous, we know that $X_n$ is Gaussian with mean $\mu_n =0$ and variance $\sigma_n^2 = \int_0^T f_n(s)^2 \, ds$. As $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu_n=0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sigma_n^2 = \int_0^T f(s)^2 \, ds$, it follows that the limit $X=\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n$ is Gaussian with mean zero and variance $\int_0^T f(s)^2 \, ds$ (this can be shown e.g. by using that the characteristic function of $X_n$ converges pointwise to the characteristic function of $X$).

> **Step 2:** Prove the assertion for continuous deterministic $f$.

For continuous deterministic functions $f$, the stochastic integral can be obtained as ($L^2$-)limit of Riemann sums: $$\int_0^T f(s) \, dW_s = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f \left( T\frac{i}{n} \right) (W_{T(i+1)/n}-W_{Ti/n}). \tag{2}$$ Using that the increments $W_{T(i+1)/n}-W_{Ti/n}$ are independent and distributed like $N(0,T/n)$, we find that

\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}\exp \left( i \xi \int_0^T f(s) \, dW_s \right) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \mathbb{E}\exp \left( i \xi f(Ti/n) (W_{T(i+1)/n}-W_{Ti/n}) \right) \\ &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \exp \left( - \xi^2 \frac{f(Ti/n)^2}{2} \frac{T}{n} \right) \\ &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \exp \left(-\xi^2 \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(Ti/n)^2 \left[ \frac{T(i+1)}{n} - \frac{Ti}{n} \right] \right) \\ &= \exp \left( - \frac{\xi^2}{2} \int_0^T f(s)^2 \,d s \right). \end{align*}

This shows that $\int_0^T f(s) \, dW_s$ is Gaussian with mean zero and variance $\int_0^T f(s)^2 \, ds$.

Comment: thank you very much :)

Comment: @saz why did you compute the expected value in the second assertion? and why did you write the terms i and ξ? Thanks

Comment: @DiogoFonseca What do you mean? I computed the characteristic function of the random variable. Note that the characteristic function uniquely characzerizes the distribution of a random variable.

Comment: @saz oh ok its the characteristic function! By looking at it I didn't notice! Thx! Would there be a way to solve this without computing the characteristic function?

Comment: @DiogoFonseca Well, yes, e.g. you can argue that the $L^2$-limit of Gaussian random variables is Gaussian. The Riemann sums on the right-hand side of $(2)$ are Gaussian, and so is their limit.

Comment: @saz Thank you! Just one more question: in the last computation how do you go from line 1 to line 2 and from 2 to 3? Could you please explain pls! It would be really helpful! Thanks once again!

Comment: From line 1 to line 2 how do i and ξ dissapear? @saz

Comment: @DiogoFonseca Since $W_{T(i+1)/n}-W_{Ti/n}$ is Gaussian with mean zero and variance $T/n$, its characteristic function is given by $$\mathbb{E}\exp(i \eta (W_{T(i+1)/n}-W_{Ti/n})) = \exp \left(- \frac{1}{2} \eta^2 \frac{T}{n} \right).$$ Use this for $\eta=\xi f(Ti/n)$.

Comment: @saz thank you it makes total sense! Just one more question!   I understand that you just plugged in the characteristic function for a $ N(0,T/n) $ and then  you substituted this =(/). But in the final expression why did the  dissapear? Shouldn’t it appear in the last expression?

Comment: @DiogoFonseca Yeah, right, should be fine now... thanks.

Comment: @saz Ok seems fine now! For this to be a normal we only need to check the expression in the exponential? If we look at the expression of the pdf of the Normal distribution we have $$ f(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \times \sqrt{2 \pi}} \times {exp}^{-\frac{1}{2} \times ({\frac{x}{\sigma}})^{2}} $$

Comment: @saz this cutted my question! If we look at the pdf we don't have the term outside the exponential is that ok? Moreover, shouldn't the variance be $$ \frac{1}{\int_{0}^{T} {f(s)}^{2} ds} $$ because the pdf would suggest this! Thanks once again!

Comment: @DiogoFonseca Note that we are not looking at the pdf but at the characteristic function. The characteristic function of a Gaussian random variable with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$ equals $$\exp(- \sigma^2 \frac{\xi^2}{2}).$$ Hence, $\sigma^2=\int_0^t f(s)^2 \, ds$ in our case.