# Distribution of $\int_0^t f(t,s)dW_s$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

I know that $\int_0^t f(s)dW_s$ has normal distribution with variance $\int_0^t f(s)^2ds$ where $W_t$ - Wiener process and $f$ is deterministic function.

But what if we have also $t$ in function? Like $\int_0^t \sin{(t-s)}$?

IT also have normal distribution with variance $\int_0^t \sin^2{(t-s)}ds$? And it's always true?

So I if I have to find a distribution of $\int_0^t W_s \cos(t-s)ds$ I use integration by parts and I get $\int_0^t \sin(t-s) dW_s$ do it Has distribution as I write above?

Comment: Please define $dW_s$ (I suppose it is a Bownian process) and maybe give a reference or a link for the claim in your first sentence, so we can have a bit of context.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. Nice question. So basically you want a generalization of this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3320316/how-can-i-show-that-int-0t-fsdw-s-sim-mathcal-n-left0-int-0t-fs2ds?rq=1 Maybe the same argument can be easily generalized. Have you already tried?